# Custom layout redraw issue on Galaxy S2,S3, and S4

Tags: android, android-layout, android-view, samsung-mobile

I have a custom Layout (extends `FrameLayout`) with a few *items* in it. Each *item* is a custom `View` that can load the corresponding object (Let's say a user's profile, display picture, etc.). These views are contained inside a few `LinearLayout`s (rows) so that I can line them up properly in the rows without problems. The rows are fixed (e.g. Items 0, 1, & 2 are always in the first row and always present, 3 & 4 are in the 2nd and so on). I use a `FrameLayout` because these rows need to overlap a bit ... think interlaced hexagons.

When the layout is loaded, all the rows are laid out on top of each other since I don't yet know the sizes.

```
protected void onMeasure (final int widthMeasureSpec, final int heightMeasureSpec)
```

Inside the `onMeasure` method, I use the provided width & height `MeasureSpec`s to calculate how much room I have. Then based on that, I calculate the maximum width & height each *item* can have and store these in 3 variables (width, height, and radius). I also calculate given the padding and spacing between the items, what the width and the height of the layout itself needs to be. Now I take these values, and create new `MeasureSpec`s with the mode set to `MeasureSpec.EXACTLY` and pass them to the super layout.

```
super.onMeasure (MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec (width, MeasureSpec.EXACTLY),
                     MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec (height, MeasureSpec.EXACTLY));
```

**Note**: Initially I used `setMeasuredDimension (width, height)` to force the size of the layout, but it suffered from the issue that I'm about to describe. Changing to the `MeasureSpec.EXACTLY` method fixed it.

```
protected void onLayout (final boolean changed, final int l, final int t, final int r, final int b)
```

Inside the `OnLayout` method, I use the values that I calculated in `onMeasure` to layout the items.  If `changed` is false, I bail because nothing has changed. Otherwise I loop through the rows and set their top margins:

```
final int rowTop = rowTop(i); // i = index of row
final LayoutParams layoutParams = (LayoutParams) row.getLayoutParams ();
layoutParams.topMargin = rowTop;
layoutParams.gravity = Gravity.TOP | Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL;
row.setLayoutParams (layoutParams);
```

This allows the rows to overlap a bit (the amount is calculated based on the sizes, padding, etc). Once I've set all the rows, I loop through the *items* and set their height and width (as calculated in `onMeasure`):

```
final ViewGroup.LayoutParams layoutParams = child.getLayoutParams ();
layoutParams.width = cellWidth;
layoutParams.height = cellHeight;
child.setLayoutParams (layoutParams);
```

This works just fine on many many devices. When I rotate the device, it recalculates all these values (prints them to log so I can confirm) and redraws everything just fine. This includes `Nexus 4`, `Cyanogenmod-7`, `Cyanogenmod-11`, `LG G3 Stock ROM`, and a `Galaxy S5`. I can load other Fragments and return to the Fragment that contains this layout and everything works as expected.

**However** things don't go as smoothly on an S2, S3, or an S4 for some reason. Unfortunately I can't include screenshots (Company IP), but I'm hoping that describing the symptoms may help.

Below, where I say *I've verified this* I mean that I used paper and pencil and drew the items to scale and it looked right.

**Rotation**
On the problematic devices when I rotate, the `onMeasure` values are calculated correctly. I've confirmed this via the log, paper, and a pencil. The `onLayout` values are also calculated correctly (verified). What I see drawn on the screen, though, is not what the calculated values tell me. The values seem to lag one rotation behind. When the device goes landscape, I see the same drawing as portrait (this should not happen unless the device is a square). When I rotate back to portrait, I now see the items drawn with landscape sizes.

**Reload**
When I load another fragment (think navigation drawer) and reload the fragment with this custom layout, the rows never expand to multiple rows (they stay fully overlapped as they are initially).

I have log output at the beginning on `onConfigurationChanged`, `onMeasure`, `onSizeChanged`, and `onLayout`, and they all print when they should and print out the values that I expect to be calculated:

```
08-28 18:14:41.498  19593-19593/<REDACTED>: config
08-28 18:14:41.518  19593-19593/<REDACTED>: measure
08-28 18:14:41.518  19593-19593/<REDACTED>: Forcing size to 1903x2374
08-28 18:14:41.518  19593-19593/<REDACTED>: measure
08-28 18:14:41.518  19593-19593/<REDACTED>: Forcing size to 1903x2374
08-28 18:14:41.538  19593-19593/<REDACTED>: size
08-28 18:14:41.538  19593-19593/<REDACTED>: layout
08-28 18:14:41.548  19593-19593/<REDACTED>: Top of row 0: 0
08-28 18:14:41.548  19593-19593/<REDACTED>: Top of row 1: 524
08-28 18:14:41.548  19593-19593/<REDACTED>: Top of row 2: 1062
08-28 18:14:41.548  19593-19593/<REDACTED>: Top of row 3: 1601
```

Has anyone ran into drawing issues on these devices?
Does my drawing problem remind you of something you've had to deal with?
If so, how did you get around it?

Comment: You say that you verified that your values calculated in the measure+layout pass are correct. *Therefore* the problem is in the drawing. Tell us a bit about how you do that

Comment: I don't do the drawing. I just say where to draw. In the `onLayout`, I set the positions and dimensions of all the elements. This works on all my test devices, except for the 3 mentioned. I have an S3 running Cyanogenmod that doesn't behave this way.

Comment: Yeah sorry, I was a bit lazy and from your wording it looked like a drawing problem. Anyway, there is a bad smell in your layout pass. Take a look at my answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- You should use `View.layout()` on each children during `onLayout()`

During the layout you really want to position your children, so you calculate their relative coordinates and call `layout()` on them, so they can proceed to set their respective `mLeft`, `mRight`, etc. and have a position on screen. Their heights and widths have just been calculated in the measure pass.

Setting the `LayoutParams` during the layout pass looks a bit like a hack and is a **bad smell**. You are at a lower level here, you shouldn't do that.

*Your case*: Take for example when you set the margins on a row. My idea is that on 'non-problematic' devices the layout pass is run twice. There you probably call `super.onLayout()`. The first time the children are not positioned correctly but the (ignored) margins are calculated correctly. You don't see this because before drawing the layout pass is triggered again (is it inside a `RelativeLayout`?) and therefore
 `FrameLayout.onLayout()` sets the right child positions based on the margins calculated on the first layout pass. On some devices the layout pass runs only once and everything breaks.

If you want to implement the layout pass for a `ViewGroup`, you probably don't want to call `super.onLayout()`. For implementation examples, refer to the code of common layouts, like `FrameLayout`. You can read about the measure and layout passes in the `View` docs.

Comment: Looks like you may have nailed it ... I'll have to test on the 3 devices when I'm back in the office (WFH today). I've re-implemented the `onLayout` method to 1. not call the super & 2. calculate the cell bounds and pass them to the cell via view.layout (l,t,r,b).